# Is there a way to filter out the Info from https://repo.packagist.org?

Tags: shell, composer-php

Composer sometimes deliveres more or less usefull/relevant/interestig "**Info from https://repo.packagist.org: ...**".

Is there a way to not show this message?

Maybe a way to route it through a custom shell command and filter out certain strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curtesy of https://github.com/composer/composer/discussions/10808#discussioncomment-3090963:

```bash
composer {whatever} 2>&1 | grep -v "#TextToRemove"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to not show this message?

The short answer is the `-q`, `--quiet` command-line option. It suppresses other output, too. Exit status is preserved.

> Maybe a way to route it through a custom shell command and filter out certain strings?

You have not shared which shell, but this is certainly possible. Given on your system there is `unbuffer(1)` and `bash(1)` as `/bin/bash`, you could have an executable named `composer` within earlier in the `PATH` than the installed `composer(1)` one that filters that line out while running `composer(1)` `unbuffer(1)`ed.

As this depends on your shell configuration it is perhaps better answered with a file named `install.sh` that can be sourced afterwards:

```bash
# usage: . ./install.sh

utility_name=composer
utility_path_name="$(which "$utility_name")"
wrapper_path="$PWD"

if [ "$wrapper_path/$utility_name" = "$utility_path_name" ]; then
  echo "$utility_name: already installed: $utility_path_name" >&2
  return 1
fi

<< STUB tee "$utility_name"
#!/bin/bash
COMPOSER="$utility_path_name"
unbuffer "\$COMPOSER" "\$@" > >(sed -u '/^.*Info from https:\/\/repo\.packagist\.org:/d' )
STUB

chmod u+x -- "$utility_name"

PATH="$wrapper_path:$PATH"

which "$utility_name"

composer --version
```

To activate the wrapper, source the `install.sh` file:

```
$ . ./install.sh
```

You can then run every `composer ...` command with this noise reduction filter.

The actual wrapper is relatively thin (output yours after sourcing `install.sh` for comparison as paths differ):

```
$ cat composer
#!/bin/bash
COMPOSER="/home/user/.local/bin/composer"
unbuffer "$COMPOSER" "$@" > >(sed -u '/^.*Info from https:\/\/repo\.packagist\.org:/d' )
```

In principle this is independent to `composer` itself, just an output filter with `sed(1)` and wrapping a command-line utility.

---

Within CI you may want to do things differently, e.g. hiding all output until an error occurs. `chronic(1)` can do this.